# Stream post URL security - Website/FB page url

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, stream

We are currently offering functionality in an iOS and Android game app to share scores on FB. We want the link in stream posts to direct people to the website promoting the game or to the page for the game on FB.

we're calling some command in the Graph called

stream.publish

providing data below

`{ "link", Settings.FacebookLinkURL },
    { "name", Settings.FacebookLinkText },
    { "picture", Settings.FacebookThumbURL },
    { "caption", msgToUse}`

According to February 2013 Breaking Changes

Stream post URL security: Links in stream posts must go to app's Canvas or Website url

Everything works fine with this disabled but when enabled, using the Website url for the game or url for FB page returns the error:

'The post's link must direct to the application's connect or canvas URL'

Is there any way to fix this without fully integrating the FB SDK for each platform?

Is there any indication of when these changes will become permanent?