# Breaking change with link field when posting to facebook feed via api

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

We have a facebook website application that posts to user home page feeds as well as feeds to pages which they administer.

Until recently everything worked fine (maybe until the beginning of the year when the 1.0 API was discontinued).  The problem turns out to be the presence of the "link" field.

All is well when posting to a user home page.  But when we post to a another page the user is an admin of (or a group), the call fails with the following error.

The error that returns is:

```
{ message: '(#200) Permissions error',
 type: 'OAuthException',
 code: 200 }
```

Removing the link field is enough to make the call work again. I had thought we might affected by  this issue: [Stream post URL security - Website/FB page url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14881123/stream-post-url-security-website-fb-page-url). However, our applications Stream post URL security migration is set to off and we are linking to a url in our domain. When posting to a home page the url can be within our app domain or without and all works fine.

As I've been testing I've boiled the calls down to the following in every version of the api.

```
{{facebookId}}/feed?link=http://cir.cl
{{pageId}}/feed?link=http://cir.cl
```

For the former we use the long-lived token we got after authenticating. For the latter we use the token returned by {{facebookId}}/accounts or {{facebookId}}/groups. The former works. The latter fails, but changing link to message=foo works fine.

Has anyone noticed a breaking change that touches on this issue?

Comment: Are you using a page access token to publish to their pages?

Comment: Yes. we are using the page access token.

Comment: So what does your request look like that you get that error for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out it's a valid bug and our friends at Facebook are addressing it:

https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/755514351208694

How often does that happen?  I'm just surprised the internet isn't blowing up about this. Dozens and dozens and dozens of applications must be affected.

Comment: Has been addressed as of mid January 2015